# Boxing экземпляра типа, определяемого во время run-time'а

Tags: c#

Возможно ли вообще с помощью этого:

- `ReadOnlySpan<byte> data` – данные структуры
- `Type type` – тип структуры

создать `object`, c типом `type` и данными `data`?

---

Для примера возьмём `int`:

```
object Box(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, Type type)
{
    <реализация>
}
object Box<T>(T value) where T : struct => (object)value;
```

Этот код:

```
Span<byte> data = stackalloc byte[4];
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(data, 15); // осторожно: вы можете не угадать с endian: тут он используется в демонтративных целях
var type = typeof(int);

var boxedInt32 = Box(data, type);
```

…будет такой же, как и этот код:

```
var int32 = 15;

var boxedInt32 = Box(int32); // (object)int32
```

…за одним исключением: в первом случае мы определяем тип во время run-time'а, а во втором – во время компиляции.

---

У меня есть наводка по этому поводу:

```
object Box(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, Type type)
{
    // checks skipped

    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    ref var objRef = ref Unsafe.As<object, byte>(ref obj);
    ref var objDataRef = ref Unsafe.Add(ref objRef, IntPtr.Size + 4); // type handle (размер указателя) + sync block index (4 байт)
    var objDataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
    var objData = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref objDataRef, objDataSize);
    data.CopyTo(objData);

    return obj;
}
```

…но я не знаю, на сколько данный метод безопасен и подойдёт ли он для разных ОС.

---

<sup>*Примечание*: Мне просто интересно, возможно ли вообще такое?</sup>

Comment: что ты ожидаешь увидеть в `boxedInt32`? `(object)int32`?

Comment: @Grundy Объект. Что же ещё?

Comment: какое значение-то?

Comment: @Grundy значение `int32`, конечно же. при unboxing'е `var unboxedInt32 = (int)boxedInt32` мы должны получить `int32 == unboxedInt32` в `true`

Comment: какое конкретное значение ты ожидаешь увидеть в твоем примере?

Comment: @Grundy `15`. Там же всё четко написано. Там могло быть и 13, и 0, и -1234567890 – любое число.

Comment: [MemoryMarshal.TryRead<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.tryread?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_MemoryMarshal_TryRead__1_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte____0__)

Comment: Не всегда записывая `15` ты получишь `15`, так как тут ты сам указываешь `endian`, при чтении ты можешь его не угадать и получить совсем не то, что ожидал

Comment: @Grundy Точно... Отдельный вопрос: в каком endian записывается `int` :) Но это не отменяет сути вопроса: как реализовать `object Box(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, Type type)`?

Comment: @Grundy Хотя, в таком случае, т. к. все комплексные типы состоят из базовых, в том числе и `int`, то придётся угадывать с endian всегда...

Comment: Выше в комментарии метод, который получает struct из span, дальше просто упаковать результат в object

Comment: Очень интересный вопрос, и ответ тоже. Но у меня другой вопрос возник, скорее всего к автору вопроса. А зачем это всё? Как это можно применить на практике? Меньше работы GC сделать,  избежать `unsafe`, или как?

Comment: @aepot прочитайте примечание в конце вопроса

Comment: Я прочитал, и вижу технологию, а куда ее даже теоретически можно было бы воткнуть - не вижу. Окей, по-другому спрошу: как вы думаете, где бы это в теории можно было бы применить, в каких алгоритмах или шаблонах?

Comment: Ну не знаю... хранить без всяких generic'ов unmanaged типы, имея возможность преобразовать их в generic `T` и в `object`. Первое – элементарно, второе – уже нет

Answer (score 2):

> но я не знаю, на сколько данный метод безопасен

На столько же, насколько безопасен любой метод, пытающийся взломать внутренние структуры CLR - примерно ненасколько. Для частного случая, когда type является примитивным типом или состоит только из примитивных типов и имеет атрибут `StructLayout` со значением LayoutKind.Sequential или LayoutKind.Explicit, существует такое решение, основанное на документированных API:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct S
    {
        public byte x;
        public byte y;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return x.ToString() + ";" + y.ToString();
        }
    }

    static object Box(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, Type type)
    {

        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            IntPtr p = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            Marshal.Copy(data.ToArray(), 0, p, data.Length);
        }
        finally { gch.Free(); }
        return obj;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object x = Box(new byte[] { 1, 2 }, typeof(S));
        Console.WriteLine(x); //Результат: 1;2

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

В общем случае, насколько я знаю, нет, стабильного решения не существует.

Comment: Тут Grundy натолкнул меня на мысль, что если внутри структуры будет мой `int`, то можно не угадать с endian при unboxing'е. Что с этим делать?

Comment: Да, именно unmanaged типы будут бокситься, т. к. managed типы могут иметь ссылки, а это уже крест на создании снимка объекта.

Comment: @return Проверить значение поля [BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.islittleendian?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Какие проблемы могут быть у такого решения, как ваше?

Comment: Там проскользнула фраза: "...стабильного решения не существует".

Comment: @return Потенциальных проблем тут может быть море. Если промахнуться с размером Span'а, можно повредить данные соседнего объекта. Но это решается просто сравнением с Marshal.SizeOf. А "стабильного решения не существует" - это про то, что вы писали выше. Если в структуре есть ссылочные типы, закрепить ее в памяти стандартными средствами нельзя, а значит стабильно получить доступ к ее байтам в данном случае не выйдет.

Comment: Можно проверить, является ли тип unmanaged с помощью `RuntimeHelpers`. Тут всё просто: это проблемы не кода а валидации.